# Unpacking a 1-tuple in a list of length 1

Tags: python, list, tuples, iterable-unpacking

Suppose I have a tuple in a list like this:

```
>>> t = [("asdf", )]
```

I know that the list always contains one 1-tuple. Currently I do this:

```
>>> dummy, = t
>>> value, = dummy
>>> value
'asdf'
```

Is there a shorter and more elegant way to do this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
>>> t = [("asdf", )]
>>> t[0][0]
'asdf'
```

Answer (score 24):

Try

```
(value,), = t
```

It's better than `t[0][0]` because it also asserts that your list contains exactly 1 tuple with 1 value in it.

Comment: I just tested this out, and it doesn't work. Unfortunately it doesn't get away from the initial list.

Comment: The example in the question works. What exactly did you try to do?

Comment: My apologies, I tried it again and it works. I'm not sure why it didn't work before; all I can think is that I left the `,` out after `value`.

Answer (score 0):

Try  `[(val, )] = t`

```
In [8]: t = [("asdf", )]

In [9]: (val, ) = t

In [10]: val
Out[10]: ('asdf',)

In [11]: [(val, )] = t

In [12]: val
Out[12]: 'asdf'
```

I don't think there is a clean way to go about it.

`val = t[0][0]` is my initial choice, but it looks kind of ugly.

`[(val, )] = t` also works but looks ugly too. I guess it depends on which is easier to read and what you want to look less ugly, `val` or `t`

I liked Lior's idea that unpacking the list and tuple contains an assert.

```
In [16]: t2 = [('asdf', ), ('qwerty', )]

In [17]: [(val, )] = t2
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-17-73a5d507863a> in <module>()
----> 1 [(val, )] = t2

ValueError: too many values to unpack
```